# Create group column with values based on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, unpivot

I have two tables **1) a customer table 2)Account table.** I want to see what accounts are primary and which are secondary accounts.

In one table I have `accountRowId` and `AccountNumber`. In the other table I have `PrimaryAccountRowId` and `SecondaryAccountRowId`.

For my output I would like to have all `AccountNumbers` in one column with all the ***AccountRelationship(primary or seconday)*** in another column beside each `AccountNumber`.

In order to join table, for `PrimaryAccounts` I would join `AccountRowId` on `PrimaryAccountRowId` and for secondary Accounts I would just flip flop and instead of having the `primaryAccountRowId` it would be `SecondaryAccountRowId`.

**My Account table:**

```
  AccountRowId = 256073
  AccountNumber = 8003564
  AccountRowId = 342300
  AccountNumber = 2034666
```

**Customer table:**

```
   PrimaryAccountRowId = 256073
   SecondaryAccountRowId = 342300
```

What I want to see my table look like

```
     AccoundNumber        AccountRelationship
      8003564             Primary
      2034666             Secondary
```

Please provide some helpful logic/code of how I would achieve these results. Thanks

Comment: `PrimaryAccountRowId` and `SecondaryAccountRowId` are two different columns or same column different values?

Comment: @DineshDB two different columns in the table, both of them join on the AccountRowId in the account table. The table was designed before I started working for the company and they made two opposite columns to be able to tell what were primary accound and secondary by a join. I want to do the above though if you can help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a left join between the two tables. Basically by checking if the accountRowid exists in the column primaryAccountRowId from customer table you would know if the account_number is a primary, similarly the logic for secondary as well

eg:

```
   select a.accountNumber
         ,max(case when p_acct.PrimaryAccountRowId is not null then 'PRIMARY' 
                   when sec_acct.PrimaryAccountRowId is not null then 'SECONDARY'
               end) as acct_relationship
     from account a
left join customer p_acct
       on a.AccountRowId =p_acct.PrimaryAccountRowId 
left join customer sec_acct
       on a.AccountRowId =sec_acct.PrimaryAccountRowId 
 group by a.accountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT AccountNumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN B.PrimaryAccountRowId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Primary'
             WHEN C.SecondaryAccountRowId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Secondary'
        END)AccountRelationship
FROM AccountTable A
LEFT JOIN CustomerTable B ON A.AccountRowId = B.PrimaryAccountRowId
LEFT JOIN CustomerTable C ON A.AccountRowId = C.SecondaryAccountRowId
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheieve this using UNION ALL.

```sql
SELECT a.AccountNumber, "Primary" AS AccountRelationship
FROM Account AS a
INNER JOIN Customer AS c
ON a.AccountRowId = c.PrimaryAccountRowId
UNION ALL
SELECT a.AccountNumber, "Secondary" AS AccountRelationship
FROM Account AS a
INNER JOIN Customer AS c
ON a.AccountRowId = c.SecondaryAccountRowId
```